# Uploading a file in Symfony2.3

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I've been having a problem trying to upload a single file with Symfony2.3. When I try to upload the file I get the following error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function move() on a non-object in
```

I have checked `$csvFileForm['csvFile']->getData();` and its a string (the name of the file), also `$file = $this->getRequest()->files;` has size zero.

Here is the show action:

```php
/**
 * Finds and displays a Project entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="console_project_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $csvFileForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('csvFile', 'file')
        ->getForm();

    return array(
        'csvFileForm' => $csvFileForm->createView()
    );
}
```

and the form in the template looks like this:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ path('console_project_upload_urls', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" >
  {{ form_row(csvFileForm.csvFile) }}
  {{ form_row(csvFileForm._token) }}
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit"/>
</form>
```

The upload action is this:

```php
/**
 * Lists all Project entities.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/upload-urls", name="console_project_upload_urls")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function uploadUrlsAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $csvFileForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('csvFile', 'file')
        ->getForm();

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $csvFileForm->handleRequest($request);

    $data = $csvFileForm['csvFile']->getData();
    $data->move(".", "something.csv"); // This is where the exception occurs

    $file = $this->getRequest()->files; // I have used this to check the size of the array

    return $this->redirect(...);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add the [enctype](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-enctype-view) to your form tag.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ path('console_project_upload_urls', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    ...
</form>
```

**Note**: This is deprecated as of Symfony2.3 and will be removed in Symfony3. You should  use the new [form_start()](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-start-view-variables) twig helper.

```
{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'POST', 'action': path('console_project_upload_urls', { 'id': entity.id })}) }}
     ...
{{ form_end(form) }}
```